# Android Smart Contract SendAsync Issue

Tags: java, android, ethereum

## Issue

When deploying a smart contract to the private blockchain and trying to execute a SendAsync on the method call in the smart contract through an Android Studio application we get a message back in the console that states the following message: I/System.out: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@427c299[Not completed].
The issue is with the variable named VarName located in my MainActivity.java file shown below.

I have tried to solve this issue by doing the traditional java method of creating a transaction receipt, but Android does not appear to support this.
The reason I know it is an issue is that if I go to remix and try to call the getState method I receive the default value thus indicating the data was not sent.

**Note**) I have been able to receive data back from my smart contract through the method getState.

### Steps To Reproduce

You will need to create a blank activity project and ensure to enable internet activity for the android application. 
Next, copy and paste the following code into your MainActivity.java file.

```java
package com.example.testingsmartcontractcode;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService;
import org.web3j.tx.gas.ContractGasProvider;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Web3j web3j;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("ws://10.0.2.2:8545"));
        String Account = null;
        try {
            Account = web3j.ethAccounts().sendAsync().get().getAccounts().get(0);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("ETHEREUM-Account", Account);
        ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider = new ContractGasProvider() {
            @Override
            public BigInteger getGasPrice(String contractFunc) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public BigInteger getGasPrice() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public BigInteger getGasLimit(String contractFunc) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public BigInteger getGasLimit() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(Account);
        String contractAddress = "0xf51c2b55B7AF741C9dB105adFC2FB7290f442CA8";
        Hello contract = Hello.load(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
        String VarName = null;
        try {

            VarName = contract.name().sendAsync().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("ETHEREUM", VarName);
        try {
            System.out.println(contract.sendData("Hello").sendAsync());
//            TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = contract.sendData("Hello").send();
//            System.out.println(transactionReceipt.getBlockNumber());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The Following Hello.java file to copy over is:

```java
package com.example.testingsmartcontractcode;


import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.web3j.abi.TypeReference;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Function;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Type;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String;
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteFunctionCall;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt;
import org.web3j.tx.Contract;
import org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager;
import org.web3j.tx.gas.ContractGasProvider;

/**
 * <p>Auto generated code.
 * <p><strong>Do not modify!</strong>
 * <p>Please use the <a href="https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html">web3j command line tools</a>,
 * or the org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator in the
 * <a href="https://github.com/web3j/web3j/tree/master/codegen">codegen module</a> to update.
 *
 * <p>Generated with web3j version 4.5.6.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class Hello extends Contract {
    private static final String BINARY = "{\n"
            + "\t\"linkReferences\": {},\n"
            + "\t\"object\": \"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\",\n"
            + "\t\"opcodes\": \"PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE PUSH1 0x40 DUP1 MLOAD SWAP1 DUP2 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE DUP1 PUSH1 0xB DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD PUSH32 0x48656C6C6F20576F726C64000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 DUP2 MSTORE POP PUSH1 0x0 SWAP1 DUP1 MLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 PUSH2 0x4F SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH2 0x62 JUMP JUMPDEST POP CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x5C JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH2 0x107 JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP2 PUSH1 0x1 AND ISZERO PUSH2 0x100 MUL SUB AND PUSH1 0x2 SWAP1 DIV SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x0 KECCAK256 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1F ADD PUSH1 0x20 SWAP1 DIV DUP2 ADD SWAP3 DUP3 PUSH1 0x1F LT PUSH2 0xA3 JUMPI DUP1 MLOAD PUSH1 0xFF NOT AND DUP4 DUP1 ADD OR DUP6 SSTORE PUSH2 0xD1 JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 DUP1 ADD PUSH1 0x1 ADD DUP6 SSTORE DUP3 ISZERO PUSH2 0xD1 JUMPI SWAP2 DUP3 ADD JUMPDEST DUP3 DUP2 GT ISZERO PUSH2 0xD0 JUMPI DUP3 MLOAD DUP3 SSTORE SWAP2 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1 ADD SWAP1 PUSH2 0xB5 JUMP JUMPDEST JUMPDEST POP SWAP1 POP PUSH2 0xDE SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH2 0xE2 JUMP JUMPDEST POP SWAP1 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x104 SWAP2 SWAP1 JUMPDEST DUP1 DUP3 GT ISZERO PUSH2 0x100 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 PUSH1 0x0 SWAP1 SSTORE POP PUSH1 0x1 ADD PUSH2 0xE8 JUMP JUMPDEST POP SWAP1 JUMP JUMPDEST SWAP1 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x44F DUP1 PUSH2 0x116 PUSH1 0x0 CODECOPY PUSH1 0x0 RETURN INVALID PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x10 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH1 0x4 CALLDATASIZE LT PUSH2 0x5E JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 CALLDATALOAD PUSH29 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SWAP1 DIV DUP1 PUSH4 0x6FDDE03 EQ PUSH2 0x63 JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0x1865C57D EQ PUSH2 0xE6 JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0x9231A545 EQ PUSH2 0x169 JUMPI JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x6B PUSH2 0x224 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 DUP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP3 DUP2 SUB DUP3 MSTORE DUP4 DUP2 DUP2 MLOAD DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP DUP1 MLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 DUP1 DUP4 DUP4 PUSH1 0x0 JUMPDEST DUP4 DUP2 LT ISZERO PUSH2 0xAB JUMPI DUP1 DUP3 ADD MLOAD DUP2 DUP5 ADD MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 DUP2 ADD SWAP1 POP PUSH2 0x90 JUMP JUMPDEST POP POP POP POP SWAP1 POP SWAP1 DUP2 ADD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1F AND DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0xD8 JUMPI DUP1 DUP3 SUB DUP1 MLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP4 PUSH1 0x20 SUB PUSH2 0x100 EXP SUB NOT AND DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP JUMPDEST POP SWAP3 POP POP POP PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST PUSH2 0xEE PUSH2 0x2C2 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 DUP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP3 DUP2 SUB DUP3 MSTORE DUP4 DUP2 DUP2 MLOAD DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP DUP1 MLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 DUP1 DUP4 DUP4 PUSH1 0x0 JUMPDEST DUP4 DUP2 LT ISZERO PUSH2 0x12E JUMPI DUP1 DUP3 ADD MLOAD DUP2 DUP5 ADD MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 DUP2 ADD SWAP1 POP PUSH2 0x113 JUMP JUMPDEST POP POP POP POP SWAP1 POP SWAP1 DUP2 ADD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1F AND DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x15B JUMPI DUP1 DUP3 SUB DUP1 MLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP4 PUSH1 0x20 SUB PUSH2 0x100 EXP SUB NOT AND DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP JUMPDEST POP SWAP3 POP POP POP PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x222 PUSH1 0x4 DUP1 CALLDATASIZE SUB PUSH1 0x20 DUP2 LT ISZERO PUSH2 0x17F JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST DUP2 ADD SWAP1 DUP1 DUP1 CALLDATALOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 PUSH5 0x100000000 DUP2 GT ISZERO PUSH2 0x19C JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST DUP3 ADD DUP4 PUSH1 0x20 DUP3 ADD GT ISZERO PUSH2 0x1AE JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST DUP1 CALLDATALOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 DUP5 PUSH1 0x1 DUP4 MUL DUP5 ADD GT PUSH5 0x100000000 DUP4 GT OR ISZERO PUSH2 0x1D0 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP1 DUP1 PUSH1 0x1F ADD PUSH1 0x20 DUP1 SWAP2 DIV MUL PUSH1 0x20 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD SWAP1 DUP2 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE DUP1 SWAP4 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP2 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP4 DUP4 DUP1 DUP3 DUP5 CALLDATACOPY PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 DUP5 ADD MSTORE PUSH1 0x1F NOT PUSH1 0x1F DUP3 ADD AND SWAP1 POP DUP1 DUP4 ADD SWAP3 POP POP POP POP POP POP POP SWAP2 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP3 SWAP1 POP POP POP PUSH2 0x364 JUMP JUMPDEST STOP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP2 PUSH1 0x1 AND ISZERO PUSH2 0x100 MUL SUB AND PUSH1 0x2 SWAP1 DIV DUP1 PUSH1 0x1F ADD PUSH1 0x20 DUP1 SWAP2 DIV MUL PUSH1 0x20 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD SWAP1 DUP2 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE DUP1 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP2 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP3 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP2 PUSH1 0x1 AND ISZERO PUSH2 0x100 MUL SUB AND PUSH1 0x2 SWAP1 DIV DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x2BA JUMPI DUP1 PUSH1 0x1F LT PUSH2 0x28F JUMPI PUSH2 0x100 DUP1 DUP4 SLOAD DIV MUL DUP4 MSTORE SWAP2 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 PUSH2 0x2BA JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 ADD SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x0 KECCAK256 SWAP1 JUMPDEST DUP2 SLOAD DUP2 MSTORE SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1 ADD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP1 DUP4 GT PUSH2 0x29D JUMPI DUP3 SWAP1 SUB PUSH1 0x1F AND DUP3 ADD SWAP2 JUMPDEST POP POP POP POP POP DUP2 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x60 PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP2 PUSH1 0x1 AND ISZERO PUSH2 0x100 MUL SUB AND PUSH1 0x2 SWAP1 DIV DUP1 PUSH1 0x1F ADD PUSH1 0x20 DUP1 SWAP2 DIV MUL PUSH1 0x20 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD SWAP1 DUP2 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE DUP1 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP2 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP3 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP2 PUSH1 0x1 AND ISZERO PUSH2 0x100 MUL SUB AND PUSH1 0x2 SWAP1 DIV DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x35A JUMPI DUP1 PUSH1 0x1F LT PUSH2 0x32F JUMPI PUSH2 0x100 DUP1 DUP4 SLOAD DIV MUL DUP4 MSTORE SWAP2 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 PUSH2 0x35A JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 ADD SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x0 KECCAK256 SWAP1 JUMPDEST DUP2 SLOAD DUP2 MSTORE SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1 ADD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP1 DUP4 GT PUSH2 0x33D JUMPI DUP3 SWAP1 SUB PUSH1 0x1F AND DUP3 ADD SWAP2 JUMPDEST POP POP POP POP POP SWAP1 POP SWAP1 JUMP JUMPDEST DUP1 PUSH1 0x0 SWAP1 DUP1 MLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 PUSH2 0x37A SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH2 0x37E JUMP JUMPDEST POP POP JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH1 0x1 DUP2 PUSH1 0x1 AND ISZERO PUSH2 0x100 MUL SUB AND PUSH1 0x2 SWAP1 DIV SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x0 KECCAK256 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1F ADD PUSH1 0x20 SWAP1 DIV DUP2 ADD SWAP3 DUP3 PUSH1 0x1F LT PUSH2 0x3BF JUMPI DUP1 MLOAD PUSH1 0xFF NOT AND DUP4 DUP1 ADD OR DUP6 SSTORE PUSH2 0x3ED JUMP JUMPDEST DUP3 DUP1 ADD PUSH1 0x1 ADD DUP6 SSTORE DUP3 ISZERO PUSH2 0x3ED JUMPI SWAP2 DUP3 ADD JUMPDEST DUP3 DUP2 GT ISZERO PUSH2 0x3EC JUMPI DUP3 MLOAD DUP3 SSTORE SWAP2 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x1 ADD SWAP1 PUSH2 0x3D1 JUMP JUMPDEST JUMPDEST POP SWAP1 POP PUSH2 0x3FA SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH2 0x3FE JUMP JUMPDEST POP SWAP1 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x420 SWAP2 SWAP1 JUMPDEST DUP1 DUP3 GT ISZERO PUSH2 0x41C JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 PUSH1 0x0 SWAP1 SSTORE POP PUSH1 0x1 ADD PUSH2 0x404 JUMP JUMPDEST POP SWAP1 JUMP JUMPDEST SWAP1 JUMP INVALID LOG1 PUSH6 0x627A7A723058 KECCAK256 SELFDESTRUCT DIFFICULTY PUSH15 0x7B0CECECED776FDC8A22ECC735C11F DUP11 0xd7 PUSH18 0x4D1FE7D77989C982F3B75900290000000000 \",\n"
            + "\t\"sourceMap\": \"24:197:0:-;;;41:34;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::i;:::-;;24:197;8:9:-1;5:2;;;30:1;27;20:12;5:2;24:197:0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::i;:::-;;;:::o;:::-;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::o;:::-;;;;;;;\"\n"
            + "}";

    public static final String FUNC_NAME = "name";

    public static final String FUNC_GETSTATE = "getState";

    public static final String FUNC_SENDDATA = "sendData";

    @Deprecated
    protected Hello(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected Hello(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected Hello(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected Hello(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<String> name() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_NAME,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, String.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<String> getState() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETSTATE,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, String.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> sendData(String d) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_SENDDATA,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(d)),
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static Hello load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new Hello(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static Hello load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new Hello(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static Hello load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new Hello(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static Hello load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new Hello(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static RemoteCall<Hello> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Hello.class, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<Hello> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Hello.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static RemoteCall<Hello> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Hello.class, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<Hello> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Hello.class, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }
}
```

The smart contract used is Hello.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.4;
contract Hello {
string public name = "Hello World";
 function sendData(string memory d) public {
     name = d;
 }
 function getState() public view returns(string memory){
     return name;
 }
}
```

In order to interact with the smart contract and eliminate errors, you will have to use web3j core version 4.5.6.

If you are using a maven project paste **implementation('org.web3j:core:4.5.6'**) into your dependencies under your app level build.gradle scripts.

**Note**) I used both geth and testrpc to make sure neither of the environments resulted in the same issue, but they acted in both the same manner.

### Environment

- **Operating System**: Ubuntu Linux 19.04
- **Android Version**: Android Studio API version 29
- **Java Version**: JDK8

  Web3J Version:

  - **Web3j Version**: 4.5.6

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue was that I was not using the private key for my account creation.

Very silly mistake.